# Vue use object value as method name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible what I am trying to achieve here to use a value from an object as a method name?

This works great:

```
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    name: function () {
      console.log('hello')
    }
  }
});
```

But this:

```
options = {
  methodName: 'name'
};

const method = options.methodName;

Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    method: function () {
      console.log('hello')
    }
  }
});
```

Gives me the following error:

> Property or method "name" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    [method]: function () {
      console.log('hello')
    }
  }
});
```

will work. And you can spare assigning a constant by using

```
methods: {
  [options.methodName]: function() {...}
}
```